# Unable to use flask render_template on production server

Tags: python, linux, flask

On my home development server, while running following the code, everything works fine

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask("__name__")


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "<h1>Hello world</h1>"


@app.route("/test")
def test():
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Going to http://127.0.0.1:5000 correctly shows "Hello World", and /test correctly displays my html template.

However, when I try to run the same code with the same file structure on my production server, I'm able to display text using inline html ('serverIP'/ still displays "Hello World") but whenever I try to use the render_template function, It does not work ('serverIP'/test gives an Internal Server Error)

I'm sure that my html template is in the correct directory

I'm pretty new to all this, so any insight as to where the problem might be would be appreciated.
The machine running the server uses Ubuntu 18.04 and Apache if that helps

Error being thrown is: `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html`

```
.
|-- webApp
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- static
|   `-- templates
|       |-- index.html
`-- webapp.wsgi
```

Error Logs:

```
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165189 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391] ERROR:__name__:Exception on /test [GET]
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165235 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165239 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165243 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165246 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165250 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165253 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165256 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165259 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165262 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165266 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]   File "/var/www/webApp/webApp/__init__.py", line 13, in test
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165269 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]     return render_template("index.html")
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165272 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 148, in render_template
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165287 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]     ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165290 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1068, in get_or_select_template
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165293 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]     return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165296 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 997, in get_template
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165299 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]     return self._load_template(name, globals)
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165302 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 958, in _load_template
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165305 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]     template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165307 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 125, in load
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165310 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]     source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165313 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 59, in get_source
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165316 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]     return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165319 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 95, in _get_source_fast
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165322 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391]     raise TemplateNotFound(template)
[Tue Jun 15 21:26:15.165324 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9931:tid 139653360965184] [client 162.198.172.56:65391] jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I just a made dumb mistake when creating the Flask instance

`app = Flask("__name__")` should be
`app = Flask(__name__)`

Thanks for your help